# Why is ::operator new[] necessary when ::operator new is enough?

Tags: c++, memory-management, overloading, standards, new-operator

As we know, the C++ standard defines two forms of global allocation functions:

```
void* operator new(size_t);
void* operator new[](size_t);
```

And also, the draft C++ standard (18.6.1.2 n3797) says:

> 227) It is not the direct responsibility of operator
>   new or operator delete to note the repetition
>   count or element size of the array. Those operations are performed
>   elsewhere in the array new and delete expressions. The array new
>   expression, may, however, increase the size argument to operator
>   new to obtain space to store supplemental information.

What makes me confused is:

What if we remove `void* operator new[](size_t);` from the standard, and just use `void* operator new(size_t)` instead? What's the rationale to define a redundant global allocation function?

Comment: Interesting question. Usually, when adding C++ support to a C-only system, `operator new` and `operator new[]` both just turn around and call `malloc`.

Comment: Just speculating here. But it is actually a valid distinction in the case of overloading those operators for a class type, so perhaps it is consistent to make the global versions have the same interface.

Comment: The note is odd in that there is presumably no reason why the non-array version might also not `increase the size argument to operator new to obtain space to store supplemental information`, although no remark to that effect is made.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but the question is about how these two functions differ. Both just take the number of bytes to allocate. There doesn't seem to be any significant difference.

Comment: @Keith: I remembered reading somewhere in the Standard that that's specifically disallowed - found it - "it may be greater
than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array"

Comment: @TonyD, in full: "A new-expression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of
type std::size_t. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be
greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array." I would have read that as a statement about the value passed in to `void* operator new(size_t);`, not its behavior.

Comment: @Keith: you said "presumably no reason why the non-array version might also not increase the size argument to operator new to obtain space to store supplemental information" - clearly you were talking about the `new[]` *expression* as that's where the Standard says the increase is allowed - I'm just saying that the non-array equivalent is *not* allowed to do that.  If you want to speculate that it can happen elsewhere, that's fine but distinct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `::operator new[]` may have been useful for fairly specialized systems where "big but few" arrays might be allocated by a different allocator than "small but numerous" objects. However, it's currently something of a relic.

`operator new` can reasonably expect that an object will be constructed at the exact address returned, but `operator new[]` cannot. The first bytes of the allocation block might be used for a size "cookie", the array might be sparsely initialized, etc. The distinction becomes more meaningful for member `operator new`, which may be specialized for its particular class.

In any case, `::operator new[]` cannot be very essential, because `std::vector` (via `std::allocator`), which is currently the most popular way to obtain dynamic arrays, ignores it.

In modern C++, custom allocators are generally a better choice than customized `operator new`. Actually, `new` expressions should be avoided entirely in favor of container (or smart-pointer, etc) classes, which provide more exception safety.

Comment: I'm shocked, I say, shocked and dismayed that `std::vector` does not use `new[]`! Hmmph.

Comment: @einpoklum: vector requires placement news to work, and placement new with arrays is a nightmare, and trying to use `new[]` multiple times in a preallocated buffer like vector requires is outright impossible to do portably.

Comment: @david.pfx What part of this is incorrect? You vaguely mention "specialized array indexing" and "CDC, IBM, etc" but that's a long way from a specific claim, and my very first sentence covers that ground. (I did not mention memory pools, I said "allocated by a different allocator" and this covers accommodation of architectural peculiarity.) "Extra storage space for array indexing" in your answer should be elaborated; the requirements might be stricter than you think.

Comment: @einpoklum If you want, you can make your own allocator which is identical to `std::allocator` except for calling `::operator new[]` instead of `::operator new` (and corresponding `delete`). But, there is probably nothing to be gained, since every implementation is already optimized for the default `std::vector` which allocates arrays using the non-array functions.

Answer (score 7):

`::operator new[]` and ~`delete[]` facilitate memory usage debugging, being a central point to audit allocation and deallocation operations; you can then ensure the array form is used for both or neither.

There are also lots of plausible if highly unusual/crude tuning uses:

- allocate arrays from a separate pool, perhaps because that crucially improved average cache hits for small single-object dynamically-allocated objects,
- different memory access hints (ala [`madvise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html)) for array/non-array data

All that's a bit weird and outside the day-to-day concerns of 99.999% of programmers, but why prevent it being possible?

Comment: @MooingDuck: carefully note the leading "~"... O_o.

Comment: I'd figured that was a typo, I've never encountered that syntax except with pseudo destructor names.

Comment: @MooingDuck: it's a shorthand in general English usage - not a C++ notation - to say that the prefix of some previous entry appears in the same place, often used in dictionary entries; for example: *trouble* <description> *~some* <description of troublesome> ...

Comment: … English or Perl? … Following the dictionary, I'm inspired to `#define opərator operator`…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: knock yourself out... whatever swats your spud.

Answer (score 6):

The standard (n3936) makes it clear that these two operators serve different but related purposes.

`operator new` calls the function `void* operator new(std::size_t)`. The first argument must be identical to the argument to the operator. It returns a block of storage suitably aligned, and which may be somewhat larger than required.

`operator new[]` calls the function `void* operator new[](std::size_t)`. The first argument may be larger than the argument supplied to the operator, to provide extra storage space if required for array indexing. The default implement for both is to simply call malloc().

The purpose of `operator new[]` is to support specialised array indexing, if available. It has nothing to do with memory pools or anything else. In a conforming implementation that made use of this feature, the implementation would set up specialised tables in the extra space and the compiler would generate code for instructions or calls to library library support routines that made use of those tables. C++ code using arrays and failing to use new[] would fail on those platforms.

I am not personally aware of any such implementation, but it resembles the kind of features required for the support of certain mainframes (CDC, IBM, etc) which have an architecture quite unlike the Intel or RISC chips we know and love.

In my opinion, the accepted answer is incorrect.

---

Just for completeness, the standard (n3936 mostly in S5.3.4) contains the following.

1. A distinction between allocating an 'array object' or a 'non-array object'
2. References to 'array allocation overhead', with the implication that extra storage might be needed and it might (somehow) be used for a repetition count or element size.

There is no reference to memory pools or any hint that this might be a consideration.

Comment: So on those implementations `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >` wouldn't work?

Comment: @Mehrdad: They would work. It is an _optimization_ that _could_ be performed by the compiler to allocate the extra space in order to be used by (compiler-generated) specialized lookup code.

Comment: Hard to say without an actual implementation to look at.

Comment: "The purpose of operator new[] is to support specialised array indexing, if available. It has nothing to do with memory pools or anything else." - do you have any reference or personal experience to support this claim about the intent of the people involved in specifying this, or is this your deduction based on your perception of utility?

Comment: @TonyD: See edit. My reading of the standard, plus my knowledge of (largely historical) mainframe instructions sets and problems implementing C. Utility does not come into it.

Comment: Then I think you've misapprehended what that part of the Standard is about... many existing implementations store a count of the number of elements in the array at a known offset from the returned pointer so that `delete[]` can find that number and call the destructor for the appropriate number of elements - that explains all the parts of the Standard you mention.  Your "specialised array indexing" and "specialised tables" makes it sound like some cross-memory-segment fragmentation of the array in virtual address space, which is a completely different prospect, not alluded to by the Standard.

Comment: @tonyd: I disagree, but really I barely understand your point and you are reading into may answer something that simply is not there. If you have anything to add to your answer (which I think is mistaken) feel free to add to it rather than attempting to debate in the comments.

Comment: @david.pfx: I don't need your blessing to comment on your answer... you're in a public forum where requests for clarification/reference, a polite suggestion that another interpretation of the evidence you've said you based your conclusions on is possible, and a friendly mention that your answer might be misinterpeted is par for the course. It's partly offered for the sake of people reading your answer that want to know what other people think of it. You've chosen to explicitly rebuff my answer in yours (where readers may not see it) rather than comment - each to their own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are proper use-cases out there that require separate `new[]` and `new`, but I haven't encountered one yet that is uniquely possible with this separation and nothing else.

However, I see it like this: since the user calls different versions of operator `new`, the C++ standard would have been guilty of wantonly and deliberately *losing information* if they'd defined just one `operator new` and had both `new` and `new[]` forward there. There is (literally) one bit of information here, that *might* be useful to *somebody*, and I don't think people on the committee could have thrown it out in good conscience!

Besides, having to implement the extra `new[]` is a very very minor inconvenience to the rest of us, if at all, so the trade off of preserving a single bit of information wins against having to implement a single simple function in a small fraction of our programs.

Answer (score -1):

*The C++ Programming Language: Special Edition* p 423 says

_The `operator new()` and `operator delete()` functions allow a user to take over allocation and deallocation of individual objects; `operator new[]()` and `operator delete[]()` serve exactly the same role for the allocation and deallocation of arrays.

Thanks Tony D for correcting my misunderstanding of this nuance.

Wow, it's not often I'm caught out on something in C++ I'm so certain about - I must have been spending too much time in Objective-C!

**original wrong answer**

It's simple - the new[] form [invokes the constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/) on every element of a classic C array.

So it first allocates the space for all the objects, then iterates calling the constructor for each slot.

Comment: You're thinking of a `new expression`, instead of `operator new`.  Subtly different.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. I thought operator new was used to define the effects delivered by using the new expression. Are you saying that the link on cplusplus.com is also wrong?

Comment: @AndyDent: it often is (I prefer cppreference or the Standard itself) but in this case it's correct: "An expression with the new operator on an array type, first calls function operator new (i.e., this function) [...], and if this is successful, it then automatically initializes or constructs every object in the array (if needed)."  Note how that says it's the `new` expression that's responsible for calling the operator then doing the construction you describe....

Comment: edited answer to match Tony's understanding after checking the bible